# How to fix my code to get the characters before specified symbol like @ in SSDT?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, sql-server-data-tools

I am using `visual studio ssdt` (reporting services) . 
I want to retrieve substring from string.
For example: In my database, I have `7720@449943AJFDJ,7777@9r49r49 or 8888888844@dj939393` 
I want to retrieve substring from first symbol to `@`.
I use this `code = CInt(Split(Fields!PRESENTATION_NAME.Value.ToString, "@")(0))` .I didn't have any errors,but my code shows me `38505 - this's not true.`I don't have string started with `38505`.I was expecting from my code to show `7720 , 7777 or 8888888844`. Do you know how to fix that?
I upload file to see what I mean.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the text that comes before first the `@`?  If so, the `InStr` function finds the position of the first occurrence of the specified text.  This can then be used as the second parameter of the `Left` function, with 1 subtracted from it to omit the `@` from the final result.

```
Left(Fields!PRESENTATION_NAME.Value, InStr(Fields!PRESENTATION_NAME.Value, "@") - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you.The problem was in SUM(PRESENTATION_NAME.value) I removed sum and now everything is okay.Have a nice day.